# Adobe Flash: Making an Interactive Charting UI Component "from scratch" (without Flex)

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

I'm looking for resources on making an interactive charting component in Adobe Flash without  use of Flex (or, minimal use). That is, starting "from scratch" with Flash and ActionScript 3.0.

Is there recommended reading? Perhaps a good recent book on the subject, or a detailed blog article, or an open source project to look at? I'm interested in the development process, and specific design patterns (for example, extending Sprite as the logical base class for your component).

Thanks! ♥

Answer (score 0):

The best opensource resource I can think of is Axiis. Their code is available [here](http://code.google.com/p/axiis/source/browse/)

If I were you, I would seriously consider using that, instead of writing my own ;) But best of luck!